# InstantiationException issue with Anonymous Class in Android

Tags: java, android, instantiationexception

**A. I want to create Popup by using AlertDialogBox Anonymous class as below**:

```
private void showPopupChangeCurrency(final CharSequence[] items, final String title){
    ...
        myAlert = new AlertDialogBox() { //This is anonymous class

        @Override
        protected void setButtonRight() {
        ...
        }
    ...
}
```

**B. Problem:** When change orientation or language i got below **InstantiationException** FC issue:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.loudlex/com.loudlex.setting.CloudSettings}: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.loudlex.setting.CloudSettings$5: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3195)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3291)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1743)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7010)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:731)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.loudlex.setting.CloudSettings$5: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:642)
    at android.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:114)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1873)
    at android.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:122)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1010)
    at com.loudlex.utility.ConfWindow.onCreate(ConfWindow.java:60)
    at com.loudlex.setting.CloudSettings.onCreate(CloudSettings.java:105)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6786)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3148)
```

**C. Question:**
I want to know is there any solution to work fine with anonymous class.

**Note**. I known there are some method to overcome this issue, ex: by using public static nested class or separate to top level class.
Thanks

Comment: "make sure class name exists, is public, and has an **empty constructor that is public**". Is there an empty constructor of your custom class?

Comment: I think the answer is NO because CloudSettings$5 is an Anonymous class so it don't have explicit declare constructor and i think compiler also does not automatic add empty constructor for Anonymous class.

Comment: I think you should share the code. We're like doing guess work right now. :)

Comment: Sorry Sufian, for some reason i can not share the code :(

Comment: Well, you can still share the code with dummy method names/body. As it stands, you're unlikely to get anything other than guesses.

Answer (score 1):

You have three solutions:

1. Move `CloudSettings` in a separate class
2. Change your inner class to `public static`

   ```
   public static class CloudSettings extends DialogFragment
   ```
3. Calling `myAlert.setRetainInstance(true);`

   > Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity
   >   re-creation (such as from a configuration change)
   >
   > Reference:
   >   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)

Comment: Thanks, it seem there are no way with Anonymous class.